# cakephp 2.2 tree behaviour - Count the products in the given category and all subchildren recursively

Tags: cakephp

**CakePHP 2.2**

I've built a nested vertical menu for my categories using the tree behaviour. In these categories there are products. What I would like to achieve is next to the category name having the containing numbers of products in the specified category. Here is an example:

```
Automobile (100) > SUV (35)
                 > Pickup (25)
                 > Berline (40)
```

Next to the category, we can see the numbers of products within it.

I checked online and find this tutorial : http://mrphp.com.au/blog/fun-tree-behaviour-cakephp
There is a line in the "finding your data" last part that shows how to achieve that:

```
 // count the posts in the given category and all subchildren recursively
        $id = 123;
        $postCount = $this->Category->postCount($id); 
        debug($postCount);
```

The problem in this code is that it uses postCount() but in my case my categories don't have posts but products, in other words, I use a Product model and a ProductsController so it cannot work. I can I accomplish that?

[EDIT]

I found a solution. First i've created a new field in my categories table and named it product_count (singular name of the associated table). Then i added a belongsTo in my ProductsController.php. as followed:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'counterCache' => true
            )
        );
```

Finally in the foreach of my vertical menu i simply added this next to the category name :

```
$v['Category']['product_count']
```

Now it's working!

Comment: Then why not just "renaming" it accordingly then?

Comment: Thanks mark, i don't understand what you mean. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the postCount function with:

```
function productCount($id, $direct=false){
    if (!$direct) {
        $ids = array($id);
        $children = $this->children($id);
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $ids[] = $child['Category']['id'];
        }
        $id = $ids;
    }
    $this->Product->recursive = -1;
    return $this->Product->findCount(array('category_id'=>$id));
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt and thank you for your interest. I tried to include your code but as a beginner i couldn't make it work. I answered my own question to show some of my code and see how i can use your code. Thanks again